# Check boxes values returned and added to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables, binary-string

I am trying to take a row of checkboxes in a table and for each TD in the table it needs to check if the checkbox is ticked, is so it is a 1 and else its 0.
I need a for loop where I will be able to loop over each td, determin if it is checked and if so add a 1 to a binary string or else add a 0 to the binary string.

This should end with each tr having its own unique binary string from the checkboxes that have or have not been ticked. I will also want to set up each tr with its own unique ID.

The below code is what I have so far but am presumming I am going in the wrong direction.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
[ { ID: 000, binary: 0101010101 }  ]
function generate(){


$("#actionTable>tbody").children("tr").each(function(i, rowitem){
    $(rowitem).children("td").each(function(index, item){
        if (index == 0){
            var amid = $(item).data("amid");
        }

        else {
            //Handle checkbox
            var checked = $(item.firstChild).prop('checked')
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: A couple of questions... Could you [edit] the question to clarify? (1) This question is tagged `datatables` - are you actually using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), or is this just a standard HTML table? (2) I assume you have an initial state for the checkboxes - how is that provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested map() for this. The outer map iterates rows

The inner map iterates each input's  `checked` property converted to number and then to string and then joins the array for final string.

I don't know what the html looks like so have just used the row index of each row for now

```js
const res = $('tr').map((i, el) => {

  const binary = $(el).find(':checkbox').map((_, inp) => {
      return `${+inp.checked}`;
  }).get().join('');
  
  return { index: i, binary};
  
}).get()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```